# What are the top sites to purchase bitcoin from?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

As a newcomer to bitcoin, what would be the top websites for purchasing bitcoin?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend CoinBase.
Coinbase is a Bitcoin company based in San Francisco, and backed by trusted investors. Coinbase is the world’s largest Bitcoin broker, and also offers an exchange, wallet, and developer API.

Coinbase offers its brokerage services in the United States, United Kingdom, Canada, Singapore, and the following European countries: Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Finland, France, Greece, Hungary, Ireland, Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Malta, Monaco, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, San Marino, Slovakia, Slovenia, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland.

Coinbase plans to enter the Latin American market in 2016.

Coinbase has a knowledge base and email support. Coinbase “Community” can be used to ask questions and get support help.

Comment: why is the coinbase website always down, though? that's not a good sign :/